# Appgyver iOS - Como mudar a cor padrão de selecionado e não selecionado dos icones da tab-bar no iOS

Tags: ios, app

Preciso alterar a cor do icone que fica na tab-bar do app no iOS.
Na documentação anterior, fazia-se da seguinte forma (https://academy.appgyver.com/guides/129-basic-app-settings-in-configapplicationcoffee):

```
steroids.config.tabBar.tintColor = "#00aeef"
steroids.config.tabBar.tabTitleColor = "#ffffff"
steroids.config.tabBar.selectedTabTintColor = "#11aeef"
```

Tentei faze-lo da seguinte forma (no arquivo structure.coffee e app.coffee) mas sem sucesso:

```
tabBar:
tintColor: "#FFFFFF"
selectedTabTintColor: "#FFFFFF"
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer esta configuração?